# Not able to connect Django with rabbitmq using docker

Tags: python, django, docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect Django and rabbitmq using docker but I am getting this error "*socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known*" when I run docker-compose up. There is a connection failure between the Django container and rabbitmq container in producer.py even though I have given the name of rabbitmq container name in connection string.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    ports:
      - 15673:15672

    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: vhost
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    healthcheck:
      test: rabbitmq-diagnostics check_port_connectivity
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 10
    restart: always

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
```

view.py

```
from .producer import publish

class SampleView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        print('HERE')
        publish('data send', {'message':'Here'})
        return Response({'message': 'HERE'})
```

producer.py

```
import pika
import json
import os

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/vhost')
)


channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='main')


def publish(method, body):
    properties = pika.BasicProperties(method)
    # body = bytes(body)
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='main', body=body, properties=properties)


channel.close()
```

Comment: What is the result of `ping rabbitmq` in the `backend` service? Does it resolve to an IP?

Comment: ping: rabbitmq: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Is there any chance you're trying to actually run your program in the Dockerfile?  That runs in a different network environment and won't be able to connect to RabbitMQ or other containers.

Comment: Have you tried creasting a new docker network and adding both these containers on there? When even the ping is failing it would suggest that there is some network related thing going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are configuring the connection incorrectly,
two options:

1. Connection parameters:

```python
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='rabbitmq',
        port=5672,
        vhost='vhost',
        credentials=pika.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
    )
)
```

*Note that you can omit both port and credentials as you are using the default values, filling them here to provide a complete sample config.*

2. URL Parameters:

```python
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.URLParameters('amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/vhost')
)
```

As you went, you tried to provide a url as a host, so indeed it cannot resolve the value provided into an actual host.

Relevant documentation available [here](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/parameters.html)